# Why is Kennedy's father "the architect of Munich"?

Tags: plot-explanation, thirteen-days

In the movie "Thirteen Days", it is referenced multiple times that the father of Kennedy was "the architect of Munich" and might damage the USA in a serious way if Kennedy Jr. does not allow an attack on the missiles stationed in Cuba by the Russians.

**To what exactly is this referring?**

*I could not find any sources online that would tell me what exactly they mean.*

You can take a look at the respective scene in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEL45ffs2x4#t=1396).

Comment: @sonny-burnett I wanted to avoid that the player is getting embedded because it does not adhere to the time I linked. So maybe a direct link is better than an embedded version of the full movie :P

Comment: Ah, now that I see it you might be right, I thought it was just a small video and not the whole movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reference to the [Munich Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich_Agreement) made in 1938 between Germany, France, the United Kingdom, and Italy. It allowed Germany the annexation of portions of Czechoslovakia and is nowadays largely considered an act of inappropriate appeasement toward Germany, encouraging it to proceed with its agressive politics. *JFK*'s father [*Joseph Patrick Kennedy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_P._Kennedy,_Sr.#Ambassador_to_the_United_Kingdom_.281938.E2.80.931940.29) was US ambassador in Britain at the time and a supporter of Britain's appeasement politics.

Its relevance to the Cuban Missile Crisis (though, I haven't seen the movie *Thirteen Days* in particular) is, that [the moral of the Munich Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesson_of_Munich) can be seen as being that

> appeasement discredits the defenders' willingness to fight, and encourages the aggressor to escalate his demands.

They are thus afraid it might come to a repetition of the "Munich Lesson" if *JFK* stays too inactive during the crisis, encouraging the Soviets to take more severe steps, especially since his father already was a facilitator in the original Munich Agreement.

Comment: Thanks and you should watch the movie :P. It is one of my favorite political thrillers. ;)